# Displacing and bringing back the Particles in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi I have created a Particles in HTML5 Canvas code following a tutorial on cssdeck.com

What's happening right is good. URL: blauky.com/particle_test.html

When  you hover your mouse over the particles, they get dispersed and start flying away. But I am trying to bring these particles back after they have flown away a bit, like an elastic. To create an effect like the one in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSk4AWvnG8Y&feature=youtu.be

Thanks in advance, 
Zeeshan

Comment: Please show some code of the work you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are some rough code snippets to pull your particle back to starting position**

Save each particle’s initial position:

```
this.initialX;
this.initialY;

// and in setPos
this.initialX=x;
this.initialY=y;
```

Set a maximum travel distance that you will allow the particle to move from initial:

```
// let the particle get 100px from initial before starting its return
this.maxTravel=100;
```

When in motion, check if the particle is a specified distance from initialXY.

```
var dx = p.x-p.initialX;
var dy = p.y-p.initialY;

if( dx*dx+dy*dy > this.maxTravel*this.maxTravel )
```

If so,start bringing the partical back to initialXY during each new animation frame:

Here’s code snips to bring the particle back to initial position:

```
// In particle definition: track % progress in returing to initial
this.returnToInitialPercentage=100;


// In update: bring particle 1% closer to initialXY
p.returnToInitialPercentage-=1;
if(p.returnToInitialPercentage>0){
    returnParticleToInitial(p,returnToInitialPercentage)
}

// 
function returnParticleToInitial(p,percent) {
    var dx = p.x-p.initialX;
    var dy = p.y-p.initialY;
    percent/=100;
    p.x = p.initialX + dx*percent;
    p.y = p.initialY + dy*percent;
}
```

“Some assembly required!” :  Again, these are rough snips, adjust them to fit your exact needs.